# indicate correct path of folder

Tags: html

i have one big directory  namely project folder,it's address is

```
C:\Users\daviti\Desktop\project
```

in this folder,i have created  simple web site,whose main page is index html,this web site is created into  3 different languages,Georgian,Russian and English,Georgian variant is in  project folder directly and Russian and English versions are  put into  Russian and English folders ,those are in main project folder sure,name of these folders are eng and russ.i am interested what kind of path i should indicate  on links ,so that i can move from english version to another version,here is  subcode from georgian  version

```
<a href="eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"> </a>
<a href="russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="90" height="90"/></a>
```

as you see in three variant,name of main page is index.html,just is different by folders,this work fine for georgian version,but this one

```
<a href="eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"> </a>
<a href="russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="30" height="30"/></a>
```

from english version  does not work ,for example Russian link,also from Russian version

```
<a href="eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"> </a>
<a href="russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="30" height="30"/></a>
```

please help me to fix  this problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me understand...You have 3 "index.html" files : One in the C:\Users\daviti\Desktop\project, the second in the C:\Users\daviti\Desktop\project\eng folder and the third in the C:\Users\daviti\Desktop\project\russ folder ?

In this case try this solution :

In your Georgian index page write this :

```
<a href="eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"> </a>
<a href="russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="90" height="90"/></a>
```

In your english index page write this :

```
<a href="index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"> </a>
<a href="../russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"/></a>
<a href="../index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="30" height="30"/></a>
```

And in your russian index page write this :

```
<a href="../eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"> </a>
<a href="index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="30" height="30"/></a>
<a href="../index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="30" height="30"/></a>
```

Comment: if i am in english folder and want to access georgian or russian?

Comment: Yes i think, i gonna test it for you